# Java Map request attributes inside HashMap

Tags: java, hashmap

Is the below code to get/set values in my HashMap correct ?

```
Map<String, String> tmpSort = new HashMap<String, String>();    
if (myRequest.getSortdatafield() != null) {
tmpSort.put("attribute", myRequest.getSortdatafield());
}
if (myRequest.getSortorder() != null) {
tmpSort.put("descending", (myRequest.getSortorder() == "desc" ? "true" : "false"));
}
myRequest.getSort().putAll(tmpSort);
```

MyRequest class with getter/setter looks like

```
public Map<String, String> getSort() {
    return sort;
}
public void setSort(Map<String, String> sort) {
    if(sort != null){
        this.sort = sort;
    }
}
public String getSortorder() {
    return sortorder;
}
public void setSortorder(String sortorder) {
    this.sortorder = sortorder;
}
```

For some reasons, I always get the "descending" attribute as false

The JSON sent from the UI looks like

```
"sort":{"attribute":"colName","descending":true},
sort: null,
sortdatafield: "colName",
sortorder: "asc"
```

So, in effect I have to map the correct values which I get in sortdatafield/sortorder to sort.attribute AND sort.descending

Comment: To compare strings you should use equals method myRequest.getSortorder() == "desc" should be "desc".equals(myRequest.getSortorder())

Answer (score 1):

you don't use the `==` operator to compare `Strings` in Java, use `.equals()`:

```
myRequest.getSortorder().equals("desc")
```

or

```
"desc".equals(myRequest.getSortOrder())
```

as others have pointed out using the latter removes the risk of a `NullPointerException` and thus the need to perform a `null` check (at least for this reason), which may be preferable. There's also `.equalsIgnoreCase()` if case is to be ignored (don't know how strict the requirement is).

Using the `==` just compares the reference values of each `String` object for equality, which is unlikely to be what you want in most cases.

Comment: Congratulation! Possible NullPointerException

Comment: @Andremoniy how would there be a possible `NullPointerException`? OP is checking for null when they use the `==` to be replaced by my code in my answer... I didn't say to take that out...

Comment: you know, you are actually  right, but this is very bad style of code, it can be broken after refactoring

Comment: Never do this even if you check for `null` before

Comment: Agree but `"desc".equals(myRequest.getSortorder())` can be used just to be more correct ;)

Comment: @Maciejp is there a performance or design reason for that? I've always done it the other way around, figured it was just a matter of preference.

Comment: @jonk this is just to prevent getting a NPE, there's no performance gain afaik

Answer (score 1):

`==` is used to check reference equality not content equality.

```
if (myRequest.getSortorder() != null) {
    tmpSort.put("descending", ("desc".equalsIgnoreCase(myRequest.getSortorder()) ? "true" : "false"));
}
```

Comment: Thanks...are my null checks fine otherwise ?

Comment: Hard to say without knowing your logic entirely. In your case you will ignore null values, so it will never overwrite its value

Answer (score 0):

@shazin and others are totally right. I just want to improve style of your code (but without knowing your idea entire it hard to predict whether this style will work for you or not). So, I think it is bad idea check for `null` your values. It can lead to situation when actual value, you want to put into the map is `false`, but in case of `null` it will not be overwritten. So, this condition

```
if (myRequest.getSortorder() != null) {
tmpSort.put("descending", (myRequest.getSortorder() == "desc" ? "true" : "false"));
}
```

will best replaced with just one line:

```
tmpSort.put("descending", ("desc".equalsIgnoreCase(myRequest.getSortorder()) ? "true" : "false"));
```

So, possibly you don't need to check for `null` at all, because `null` value logically will be equal to `false` value in this context.

Comment: also is the way of using "tmpSort" and then doing putAll correct ?

Comment: @testndtv it will work if that's what you mean; it's the same as doing `.put(k, v)` for each value ([docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#putAll%28java.util.Map%29))